# Locating and using Radio Buttons with WebDriver

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Given the following HTML:

```
<td>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="chosenstepid">
<input type="radio" value="1355816110363,1324313696089,full" name="ChooseStep">
Click here to send forward 
<br>
<input type="hidden" value="432000000" name="Step0">
<input type="radio" value="1355816110363,1324312435553,full" name="ChooseStep">
Click here to send backwards
<br>
<input type="hidden" value="432000000" name="Step1">
</td>
```

What would be the optimal way of selecting the respective buttons, given that the 'value' attribute seems to change everytime the page is loaded afresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xpath and `following-sibling`:

```
//input[@name='chosenstepid']/following-sibling::input[1]
//input[@name='Step0']/following-sibling::input[1]
```